# android emulator doesn't display my first 'standard' helloWorld app

Tags: android, android-emulator, nexus-7

The standard new app `HelloWorld` doesn't run as it in the Android emulator.

On Apple Mac, I created an `AVD  :  Nexus7-4.3-JellyBean  ( Android 4.3 API 18 , CPU/ABI  ARM(armabi-v7a) RAM 343 VM Heap 32 / Storage 200 MiB / SD Card 128 MiB)`

then running HelloWorld from Eclipse ADT , I get the following  in the console log ( no error stated ...)

```
[2013-12-07 16:11:22 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
[2013-12-07 16:11:22 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2013-12-07 16:11:22 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2013-12-07 16:11:22 - HelloWorld] Performing com.example.helloworld.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-12-07 16:11:22 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Nexus7-4.3-JellyBean'
[2013-12-07 16:11:22 - HelloWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Nexus7-4.3-JellyBean'
```

The emulator is launched, it displays the Android log, then unlocking it with `Fn F2` I get the home page and I can see the list of apps BUT `HelloWorld` is not there.

Why can't I see any information or at least any error?

Comment: *at least iOS dev HelloWorld is running fine...* Then do it in iOS. Just avoid comments totally irrelevant for the question. Show your app code. Which IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting your adb as explained in [image: below image]

Answer (score 0):

The Console log is not complete yet, after starting the emulator, apk installing will start then launching,
Try to manually start the emulator then run your app and choose the already running emulator and see what happen.
- I wanted to post this as a comment but it takes 50 reputation to do so :)